# CIVI Volunteer data

Tags: civivolunteer

Where do I find the Volunteer Signup Data?

I created a new event, used CiviVolunteer to schedule volunteer slots.

But when I go to Manage Events > My Event > Participants, there's nothing there.

I can't find a record of it anywhere except in the contact's Activity list.

Answer (score 2):

I found that you can go to >>> Contacts >>> Contact Reports >>> Volunteer Reports.

That'll give you a table listing all of the volunteers and the events that they've signed up for.

Also, when that reports table opens up, there's a toggle button at the top - "Access"

If you hit that, you can add this report as a menu item which is handy. I added mine to the Events main menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the **Volunteers** tab of your event to view, manage, and record hours for the registered volunteers. Note that volunteers and participants are different (although it's possible for one person to both volunteer *and* participate, in which case they'd show up in both places).